# Why is this insert into IndexedDB using linq2indexedDB failing, and how can I retrieve the error?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, linq2indexeddb

I'm using the linq2indexedDB wrapper to work with IndexedDB. I'm working in TypeScript but I don't think that's really relevant to the issue - it should just explain the slightly odd syntax. I create my DB and add a number of object stores and indices (code shortened to keep to the point):

```
var databaseDefinition = [{
        version: config.version,
        objectStores: [
            { name: "Regions", objectStoreOptions: { autoIncrement: false, keyPath: "ID" } },
            { name: "Countrys", objectStoreOptions: { autoIncrement: false, keyPath: "ID" } }
            // etc.
        ],
        indexes: [
            { objectStoreName: "Countrys", propertyName: "RegionID", indexOptions: { unique: true, multirow: false } }
            // etc.
        ]
    }];
```

This works, and by inspecting my db structure in chrome F12 tools I can see the expected objectStores. I then try a simple insert operation:

```
    var region = serverData.Regions[0];
    this.db.linq.from("Regions").insert(region, region.ID).then((args) => {
        tracer.Trace("Insert success: " + args);
    }, (args) => {
        tracer.Trace("Insert failure: " + args);
    });
```

This fails, but the `args` object returned is undefined, so I have no idea of why. Can anyone explain what the issue might be and how I can go about tracing it?

**EDIT** (Removed additional code as it wasn't strictly relevant to the issue. Turning on logging, as described in Kristof's answer below, helped track down the issue, which is resolved in my own answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a small issue in the version of linq2indexedDB that I am using. The constants `IDBTransaction.READ_ONLY` and `IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE` are deprecated ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB#Adding_data_to_the_database)). A quick search and replace, substituting the above with the strings `'readonly'` and `'readwrite'` respectively, fixed the issue for me.

Kristof mentions there may also be a shim to take care of this, but I don't seem to have that in the most recent version downloaded from [codeplex](https://linq2indexeddb.codeplex.com/releases).

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure what the issue is, but there is no need to provide a key when a keypath is defined and a value for the keypath is present in the object.

I can't see all of your code, but did you create a new instance of the linq2indexeddb object?

if you did you can do the following:

```
var db = window.linq2indexedDB("dbName", dbConfig, true);
```

The last parameter will enable logging and all log results will be printed in the console output.

Another way is

```
linq2indexedDB.prototype.utilities.debug(true);
```

If you have any other questions regarding the linq2indexeddb, let me know. I wrote it ;)

Comment: Kristof - thanks for your response. I've fixed the keypath / key issue and turned on logging. The entire code and log error output are above. I'm getting a `TypeError` on the insert operation. What might cause this?

Comment: I'm working in chrome, btw, although the same error is present in IE10. I wonder if this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738364/chrome-indexeddb-implementation-issues

Comment: Not really an idea, I really need to release a new version of my lib. I have improved error handling on that. Can you provide more information except the type of the error, maybe an error code or something?

Comment: Found it: `IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE` is deprecated, or at least doesn't work in latest Chrome. Replacing this with `'readwrite'` fixes the issue, and the insert completes as expected.

Comment: Ah - did I miss downloading something?

Comment: I don't think so. Everything is in one file, I'll have to take a look at it :)

Comment: Fine. I just did a find/replace of the constants and it works great. Thanks for your work on the library - it looks tremendously useful.